# Simple git bug fix process

Tags: git

I would like to be able to work on a new feature, stop what I am doing to fix a bug, and then go back to the feature I was working on. I am using the following very simple process to do so:

0. Say I am working on a new feature in `branch_feature`, when I get notified of an urgent fix needed. I (temporarily) commit any work in progress locally to `branch_feature`
1. I switch to my local branch `prod`, get the latest code from `prod` from github (which contains the code running in production)
2. I implement and test my fix, commit it to `prod`, push it to github and deploy it
3. I switch back locally to `branch_feature`, uncommit the work in progress committed in 0 and continue working on my new feature

How do I do if I want to merge the fix I did in 2 to my working branch `branch_feature`, but without committing in any of the work in progress stuff? I dont like committing broken stuff

If I try to merge them without committing before I will get an error message:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
> by merge:

I am new to git, if you think the process above does not make sense feel free to suggest something else, but please keep it simple

Note: I use git with github and Visual Code.

Comment: "How do I do if I want to merge the fix I did in 2 to my working branch branch_feature, but without committing in any of the work in progress stuff? I dont like committing broken stuff" Actually in my opinion you're looking at it backwards. Commit early and often, broken or not. Commits are not magical or correct stages; they are just you pressing the Save button. It is totally normal to commit a WIP (work in progress); life is _always_ in progress. So do _not_ "uncommit" anything. Just merge  `prod` into your branch, or rebase onto `prod`, without uncommitting — and now carry on working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git stash` to stash the changes on your feature branch without committing. Then merge your production branch. Then pop the stash.

#### 1. Stash Your Changes

This will keep a copy of your changes on the branch without committing them.

```sh
# stash changes on current (feature branch)
git stash
# verify the changes are stashed
git stash list
# check status to ensure no local changes are there
# should show no changes
git status
```

#### 2. Merge Production Branch

Get your latest production changes by pulling them (this is done after you've made your bug fix). Then merge them into your feature branch.

```sh
# get production latest
git checkout production
git pull

# checkout feature
git checkout feature

# merge production - resolve any issues
git merge production
```

#### 3. Pop Your Stash

Pop the changes in your stash to have them applied to your feature branch after merging

```sh
git stash pop
```

At this point, your feature branch has the changes from production and will have your local changes, `unstaged`.

**Note:** You may need to handle conflicts after merging `production` and popping your stashed changes (i.e your bug fix to production conflicts with your local changes on the feature branch).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a totally fine workflow.  I have been using Git for ~8 years and I frequently follow these exact steps.

As **m_vemuri** described, [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) is another option.  The stash is a stack of short-lived temporary commits to help with this kind of scenario.  I personally find that once you become comfortable working with commits, stashes can feel a bit clunky to work with, but I still use them very frequently.

Another common solution is [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), where you keep a single "clean" worktree at all times for hotfixes.

> I dont like committing broken stuff

Don't be afraid to commit work-in-progress things.  Most Git operations operate on commits as opposed to working changes, so embracing commits will just give you more power in the long run.

For example, you can take a bunch of commits that are individually "broken" and use `git rebase --interactive` to squash them down into smaller "correct" commits before pushing to `origin`.

As another example, Git saves snapshots of its state after every operation, allowing you to recover from bad state via `git reflog`.  However, it only saves changes that existed in an object (commit, stash, etc) at some point.  So if you have a lot of uncommitted changes to a file and something corrupts your Git repo, you will have no way to recover those changes.

Commit early, commit often.